# Android resetting all fields of a class

Tags: java, android, class, variables, field

Hey guys I have a class called UserData consisting of static fields, which is as follows:

```
    public class UserData  {
private static JSONObject fbProfilePicture;
private static boolean loggedOut=false;
private static Integer commonFriendID;
private static Integer userID1;
private static Integer UserID2;
private static JSONObject stolenTrio=null;
}
```

Actually the class contains alot more fields but I decided to show you a small version of my class.
In my app, I've a feature to delete account and create a new one, when I choose to do that, my app goes back to the sign up process, but there's a problem, I want to clear all fields of that class after deleting user.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why are all of these `static`?

Comment: As @JoeC alluded to, you should probably use non-static properties and create an instance of UserData per login. That way, you can simply create a new instance of UserData and you'll have empty properties.

Comment: @Joe C because I do not create an object of UserData,in my app I use it as follows UserData.get/set() since I don't need more than one object in my App

Comment: @AlfieWoodland I can't because I'm using these fields in more than 50 classes, that's why I do not create an object of the class and made them all static

Comment: @AhmedKhairy then you should refactor your references chain (deeply)... It's ugly as hell to couple more than 50 classes to a single class (that could be named spaghetti code)... the "static" part is not your biggest concern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that reset your values. You might want later to do more things into that method. Ex inform a listener that your object has been cleared.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you need a static / singleton kind of instance of `UserData`, I suggest doing it like this:

```
public class UserDataSingleton {
   public static UserData userdata; 
}
```

and make your `UserData` a simple Pojo with non-static fields. 
This way you can reset your data with

```
UserDataSingleton.userData = new UserData()
```

Comment: ... or provide a method "public static void clear(){}" in UserData that does the job...